# Can't connect to Azure File Storage using "net use" command - System error 2148073478

Tags: network-share, azure, server-message-block

After the update of [Azure File storage sept. 28/29 2015](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/) I am no longer able to connect to my Azure File Storage, from my Azure Windows Server 2012R2 virtual machine.

I try to connect and map the File storage as network drives using the "net use" command.

```
cmdkey /add:<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net /user:<storage-account-name> /pass:<storage-account-key>
net use <drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name>
```

But i get the error message:

```
CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
net : System error 2148073478 has occurred.
At C:\BackupScripts\Map networkdrives.ps1:5 char:1
+ net use Y: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name>
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 2148073478 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

However I am perfectly able to connect to the File storage using the exact same command from my on-premises Windows 10 machine.

I have already tried the 'Disable "Secure Negotiate" on the client' workaround described in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2686098 But that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by rebooting the machine, even though it wasn't nice to reboot the production environment, it solved the problem.